Ionic and XCode compatibility issues
I am working on an Ionic application for which I tried to generate the iOS build from XCode. But, as a last minute surprise, we got the following error.

I understood from the warning and own research that we have to upgrade the Xcode version to 15(with iOS SDK 17+ support). I updated MAC OS and XCode and also iOS Simulator 17.5 and able to generate the build.
Coming to the query, if we build with iOS SDK 17.5, will existing application features still support as earlier(with iOS version 16.2)?

try to update you Cordova or Capacitor version.
